# Possible to add a collaborator w/ push access only to a specific folder in a repo?

Tags: git, github

I have a math based project where I want all members to have push rights to their own folder within this project but not to other member's folders.

```
Project/
    Dan/
    John/
    Sarah/
    Becky/
    Master/
    data.csv
    README.md
```

This is how everything is currently organized. Each member has their own folder where they can keep their work and then during group meetings we discuss different approaches and take the best methods and update the Master folder. This allows everyone in the group to learn from each other. I'm still relatively new to git and github so I'm not sure if this is the best approach but it seems to work. Is it possible to add collaborators ONLY to their folder within the repo? or should I structure this different somehow? In the future this group will work on many different projects so each repo would be a new project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible.
One solution is to use GitHub Pull Requests, here's what you need to do:

- Only allow you to push/accept
- Others get read-only right to the repo
- They fork the repo and do their work there
- They create a Pull Request and ONLY YOU can decide to merge or not