# Git Give Access to Users For Their Respective Work Folder

Tags: git, permissions

Can I create Multiple Folders and give access to each users according to there respective work folders in git. Is it possible ?

```
    /MyProjectGroup/
        ++ /Project1/
           ++ /Documents/ -> access to document people
           ++ /Source/ -> access to developers
             ++ /v1.0/ 
             ++ /v2.0/
           ++ /Designs/ -> access to Designers
        ++ /Project2/
           ++ /Documents/ -> access to document people
           ++ /Source/ -> access to developers
             ++ /v1.0/ 
             ++ /v2.0/
           ++ /Designs/ -> access to Designers
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to add a collaborator w/ push access only to a specific folder in a repo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32144896/possible-to-add-a-collaborator-w-push-access-only-to-a-specific-folder-in-a-rep)

Comment: I would recommend that access control be a function of the file system, not Git. Is this one large repo, one repo per project, or one repo per "work folder"?

Comment: @Frelling Yes It is a large repo as I need to create 50+ Projects and each project should have all the sub folders and I can give access to respective folders

Comment: No disrespect intended, it sounds like you are coming from an SVN or CVS world. I would strongly suggest that you consider one repo per project to leverage Git's abilities and for sanity's sake also. As far as access control, that is not a primary Git function, though there may be 3rd-party modules that provide such.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible ?

Not directly, like you would in SVN (Subversion)

You could add **[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#overview)** in order to manage those permissions... if you have access to the Git repo server.
If not, it is best to keep those folders as separate repos, and group the design and code part as **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)** of a parent repo.
That would represent *a lot of* repos though.

But remember: with Git :

- You could limit write access (push) with gitolite, or with protected branches
- BUT: you can limit read access (clone, fetch) only at the repo level (not part of a repo). That is why managing separate repo is more precise.